# XML Document in MarkLogic not getting deleted

Tags: marklogic, nuxeo

I am deleting the document from nuxeo but it's corresponding xml files not getting deleted from Marklogic database .

Comment: Add a bit more info, please - like the log messages from MarkLogic to prove that your nuexo setup is even hitting MarkLogic (the default port for nuxeo is 8010, but check you configuration.

You also do not state if this is a new setup and if you have verified that other features worked and then stopped working. Nuxeo has many manual steps related to permissions as part of the setup, so there could be alot going on. But until you give more for people to chew on, there is likely not much people can do other than take blind stabs in the dark..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here are some [tips to asking a question with enough information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that others will be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

In the base Nuxeo platform, deleting a document does not actually delete it from storage, it's just moved to a *deleted* lifecycle state, corresponding to a trash abstraction. To do the actual physical deletion you must empty the trash (`Manage` tab, `Trash` subtab as an Administrator).

Comment: Thanks @Florent for answer. Do you mean to empty the trash from the Marklogic database. Also in marklogic do i need to restart too as deletion is  cold operation  ( ref : https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/hotcold#id_14838 )

Comment: I'm talking about the Nuxeo trash. I don't see why you would need to restart MarkLogic.

Comment: i was doing empty trash too in nuxeo. When it is marking for deletion it is actually not deleting from Database. searching for more ,,may be it is due to indexes but not sure. Still have to hunt ..